# Dynamically Loaded Images Won’t Render in Ionic App

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, mobile

After upgrading to Ionic version 1.0.0-beta.14, my dynamically generated images no longer render. The image links are pulled in from a `$http.get` call. I've output the results to the console and the link is present. This only occurs in the build, when viewing the files on the web or in Ionic Lab, they appear just fine. I have switched src to `ng-src`, added Crosswalk to my build, and tried to resolve the promise in the `.config()` function before the controller is called. Any suggestions?

Here's a snippet:

```
<div class="feed" ng-repeat="result in results.data">
     <div class="row">
         <img ng-src="http://graph.facebook.com/{{result.from.id}}/picture?type=small" class="fbProPic" />
         <h4 class="col-md-5 fromUser">{{result.from.name}}</h4> 
         <h6 class="col-md-offset-11 pull-right postDate">{{result.created_time | date: 'medium'}}</h6>
     </div>
<a href="{{result.link}}" target="_blank"><img ng-src="{{result.picture}}" class="postPicture" /></a>
```

The first tag renders the image since it's just a link directly from FB. The second IMG, which is a full dynamic link does not render. This was all working prior to upgrading from beta 7 to beta 14.

Answer (score 0):

After further digging, I discovered that the issue lied with the domain access set in the project's config.xml.  In attempts to lock down the app a bit, I restricted access to certain domains.  The image files had different domains than those that were granted access.  Changing the whitelist in the app.js file did not override this change, unfortunately, so I manually added their domains to the config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been way too long, I had same problem today. modify your code from this:

```
 <a href="{{result.link}}" target="_blank"><img ng-src="{{result.picture}}" class="postPicture" /></a>
```

to this:

```
 <a href="{{result.link}}" target="_blank"><img ng-src={{result.picture}} class="postPicture" /></a>
```

I hoped this helped someone.